# Additional documents for CV

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Is it planned to be able to add additional documents to the experience section?

For example, if I wanted to add a letter of reference from my previous employer or a detailed overview of tasks and responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

A "Detailed Overview of Tasks and Responsibilities" -- that's what your CV is for.  [See mine for an example](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker).

As far as "Letters of Reference"; they're something you can send to the company with a cover letter and a resume; but if you want them publicly available I'd link to them from your blog and include the link in the CV.

For example, maybe a sentence like the following in your Personal Statement or 'Background':

> I get things done and impressed my previous employer enough [that he wrote about it](http://example.com/example-reference-letter).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Having the overview included that way is fine for me but having to split up the cv related stuff (reference letters) isn't that good, in my opinion. I have to maintain two places then.